# Node Directory Watch Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a VERY simple Node.js script that watches a directory called 'in' and when a file is dropped in there it gzip's it to 'out', then removes (unlinks) the original file... however at the unlink stage I get an error emitted from the original input stream.

```
var fs     = require('fs');
var zlib   = require('zlib');

fs.watch(__dirname + '/in', function (event, filename) {
  var gzip = zlib.createGzip();

  var inputPath  = 'in/' + filename;
  var outputPath = 'out/' + filename + '.gz';

  var inputStream  = fs.createReadStream(inputPath);
  var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);

  outputStream.on('finish', function () {
    fs.unlink(inputPath);
  });

  inputStream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.dir(err); // Error is thrown here
  });

  inputStream
    .pipe(gzip)
    .pipe(outputStream);
});
```

The error is this:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'in/test.gif'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'in/test.gif' }
```

Which indicates the file no longer exists, however I would have thought the inputStream would have finished with the file by the time outputStream's `finish` event is fired...

Any help here to clarify my understanding of streams would be appreciated.